# How to trigger the auto-completion in a comment when referring to a non-latin user name?

Tags: support, comments, users

I want to make a comment for [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74137/9467) but because one user has a Chinese character as its user name, I failed to refer it in the comment. Shortly speaking, how to trigger the auto-completion (aka IntelliSense in Visual Studio) for a non-latin user name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a qwerty keyboard, you need to copy at least the first character from the name and paste it after `@` in order to initiate the auto-completion:

[image]

If selection from the available comments is difficult (due to hyperlinks), click on the user name and select from the user profile.

Comment: It is a bit cumbersome. :-)

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ -- of course, one could say that when trying to comment to you!  (but it's a terrific question, and i'm sure i'll get a lot of use from the answer.)  and i've discovered that if one starts copying from the right-hand side rather than the starf of the name, it's more likely to work; also true for urls.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: i see. thank you.

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ: What the ... this is you, garbage collector/higgs bosom/moderator/underground? Well, [makes sense I guess](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E3%82%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF) ... :).
Btw, you aren't by chance in any way related to our now unfortunately inactive member [xport](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2099/xport)?

Comment: @doncherry: Only god knows. :-)

Comment: @ガベージコレクタ I knew there was something going on ... :)

Comment: @doncherry: I changed to the current name because in the past we could not use non-latin characters for display name. I  tried it many times long long time ago. The chinese (in question) above inspired me to change to the current name and I believed that this is a new feature from SE.